# PGSQL - Unable to sum total of array jsonb

Tags: postgresql

Database Example values

Table name test

| id | stats |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {'notes':""},{"kicks":[{"Name":"Kevin", "ID": 99, "Amount":1}, {"Name":"Jax", "ID": 102, "Amount":2}]} |
| 456 | {'notes':""},{"kicks":[{"Name":"Kevin", "ID": 99, "Amount":1} |

So what I am expecting is that at the end I'm able to say that Kevin has 2 total and Jax 2 as well.

I've tried to do something like this

```
WITH kicktotal AS (select jsonb_array_elements(stats->'kicks') from test

--- Find total of kicks
SELECT
kicktotal.jsonb_array_elements->'Amount') AS "Kicks",
kicktotal.jsonb_array_elements->'Name') AS "Kicker"

INNER JOIN id_player ON kicktotal.jsonb_array_elements->>'ID' = id_player.id
...... --- Rest of code
GROUP BY id_player.id
```

Unfortunately, it is not grouping by player... it's giving me something like this

| ID | Kicker | Kicks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Kevin | 1 |
| 99 | Kevin | 1 |
| 102 | Jax | 2 |

What I want is

| ID | Kicker | Kicks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Kevin | 2 |
| 102 | Jax | 2 |

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the wrong data model. Don't use JSON to store tabular data.

Comment: You don't even have valid jsonb, you have multiple values without a surrounding array `[]` or object `{}`, and you have `'` quoting instead of `"`.

Comment: Anyway you are completely overcomplicating this, just unpivot it once and aggregate https://dbfiddle.uk/khuxLejV and you need to remove `id` from the grouping

Comment: Fyi @Charlieface .... I joined the company 2 days ago and it was like that. I don't overcomplicate anything... working with what I have. Sorry that offended you like that.

Comment: Nothing offended me, I'm just trying to understand what the question is. Please can you give valid JSON that actually represents the problem. And does the fiddle I linked give you the correct answer?

Comment: Worked perfectly with your solution @Charlieface Thanks a lot! appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON isn't quite valid. But guesstimating for what it might look like, it seems you can use a much simpler solution.

Just unpivot the array once, and aggregate it

```
SELECT 
  j1->'Name' AS Kicker,
  SUM((j1->'Amount')::int) AS Amount
FROM kick_total k
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(k.stats->'kicks') j1
GROUP BY
  j1->'Name';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/khuxLejV)